# Compare strings with variable data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a javascript function that I'm feeding 2 strings. A saved string, and a string with saved data:

```
var new_data = '<div data-someid="8c7883c9-2c33-45dc-b020-22c0ed1bdb93">This is some text</div>';
var saved_data = '<div data-someid="f0756125-b0f7-45de-972a-39c5d254eb27">This is some text</div>';
```

I need to check if the 2 strings are the same. If I use an if statement I would do:

`if(new_data == saved_data)`

But this would obviously would return false, since the data-someid tag does not have the same value.

Is there some way to do a comparison of these strings where it doesn't matter what value `data-someid` has, as long as it exists and has a value? And could this also be possible with multiple tags in the same string?

Edit for clarification:
I don't want to compare on just `This is some text`. It needs to be the given complete strings, but the value of the `data-someid` tag is variable.

Comment: is the div on page you are getting direclty in function ?

Comment: Yes, both strings are accessible in the function

Answer (score 1):

so you need to check if the inner text is same regardless of their ids?

then compare their inner text only by using

```
if ( $( new_data ).text() == $( saved_data ).text() )
{
  //alert("yes it is same");
}
```

Comment: No, I need to check those complete strings, but the value of the data-someid tag is variable (as the title suggests)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(new_data).data('new_data') == $(new_data).data('saved_data')
```

and

```
$(new_data).text() == $(new_data).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per yours question you can do it like this

```
var new_data = '<div data-someid="8c7883c9-2c33-45dc-b020-22c0ed1bdb93">This is some text</div>';
var saved_data = '<div data-someid="abc">This is some text</div>';
if ( ($( new_data ).text() == $( saved_data ).text())&&($(new_data).data('someid'))&&($(saved_data).data('someid')))
{
  console.log("both are same");
}
else 
{console.log("both are not same")}
```

Here its checking the value first then checking if both have data-attribute.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

The following code will achieve what you are asking

```
var $newData = $(new_data);
var newDataHasId = !!$newData.data('someid');
var newDataValue = $newData.text();

var $savedData = $(saved_data);
var savedDataHasId = !!$savedData.data('someid');
var savedDataValue = $savedData.text();
if ( newDataHasId && savedDataHasId && savedDataValue === newDataValue ){
   // yep
}
```

It will convert both the strings to actual DOMElements and then extract the textContents. The non jQuery way for the same will be

```
function hasId(element){
  return !!element.dataset['someid'];
}

function extractText(element){
  return element.textContent;
}

function hydrateElement(str){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str;
  return div.children[0];
}

var newDataEl = hydrateElement(new_data);
var savedDataEl = hydrateElement(saved_data);
var newDataVal = extractText(newDataEl);
var savedDataVal = extractText(savedDataVal);

if ( hasId(newDataEl) && hasId(oldDataEl) && newDataVal === savedDataVal) {
  //yep
}
```

Also, please don't save MARKUP in database !

Comment: I used the 2 strings as an example. The question is if I can compare the 2 strings regardless of what's the output is between data-someid is. Something like data-someid="*"

Comment: @GuidoVisser my code only checks if the someId exists

Comment: As a hack though you can abuse the CSS querySelectorAll ;-) to check the data-someId being present in multiple children.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to get the textcontent in side div elements and what you are getting is only the string value as you have specified, then you can use substring function to extract the text.

Example

```
var newDataStr = new_data.substring((new_data.indexOf('>')+1),new_data.lastIndexOf('<'))

var saveDataStr = saved_data.substring((saved_data.indexOf('>')+1),saved_data.lastIndexOf('<'))
```

And then you can compare these new string values you get.

Note: you can use this way if you have string with specific format. In this case format is "Some text"
You can modify substring function's values as require.

You can also replace value of some-id with empty string (" ") using substring function same as in example code and store it in some other string variable and check for equality.

Answer (score -1):

```
var new_data = '<div data-someid="8c7883c9-2c33-45dc-b020-22c0ed1bdb93">This is some text</div>';
var saved_data = '<div data-someid="f0756125-b0f7-45de-972a-39c5d254eb27">This is some text</div>';

var text1 = new_data.split('"');
text1.splice(1,1);//taking out the data-someid
var text2 = saved_data.split('"');
text2.splice(1,1);//taking out the data-someid

if(text1.join('')==text2.join('')){ //code };
```

Comment: The div part is not getting printend . On the code part use the below variables and the code works well .                                                                                                                   var new_data = '<div data-someid="8c7883c9-2c33-45dc-b020-22c0ed1bdb93">This is some text</div>';
var saved_data = '<div data-someid="f0756125-b0f7-45de-972a-39c5d254eb27">This is some text</div>';